# How to control template resolution if both Author and Category filter in place?

Tags: categories, templates, author

The following url resolves to the category template:
http://localhost/author/myusername/?category_name=somecategory

I have a `category-somecategory.php` template and just a generic `author.php` template.  Is there any way to make such a url use the `author.php` template instead of the `category-somecategory.php`?  If not how can I filter on both category and author and force it to use the author template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the template loaded by hooking onto `template_include`, checking if `is_author` and `is_category` are both set, then switch the template for inclusion to the author template instead.

Give this a shot..

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_template_setter' );
function my_template_setter( $template ) {
    if( is_author() && is_category() && is_archive() )
        $template = get_author_template();
    return $template;
}
```

You can do any number of conditional checks here before modifying which template gets loaded.

WordPress has several template fetching functions available already, i've used one in the example, but here's a list for quick reference...

```
get_404_template()
get_search_template()
get_taxonomy_template()
get_front_page_template()
get_home_template()
get_attachment_template()
get_single_template()
get_page_template()
get_category_template()
get_tag_template()
get_author_template()
get_date_template()
get_archive_template()
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Haven't tried using it yet (priority of this requirement got pushed down) but it appears like it should work so I'll give the accept.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: Just wanted to report back that it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this could be done with [Custom Queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries).